# convert json format to csv nodejs

Tags: node.js

Sorry, this might be a duplicate question, but I could not find a solution.  Please give me some help:

```
const data = [
  {
    "Month": "V",
    "6/2022": "2",
    "7/2022": "4",
  },
  {
    "Month": "L",
    "6/2022": "6",
    "7/2022": "8",
  },
];
```

I need a CSV (semicolon, that is) like

```
Month;V;L
6/2022;2;6
7/2022;4;8
```

This is what I tried without improvement:

```
"// Extracting headers
const headers = Object.keys(data[0]);

// Extracting data rows
const rows = data.map(item => Object.values(item));

// Writing to CSV file
const csvContent = [headers, ...rows].map(row => row.join(';')).join('\n');
"
```

Comment: csv files do not have semicolon in them.. CSV means Comma-Separated-Values. Please check what the specification for csv format is.

Comment: @AniketPandey actually it depends on the implementation. For example if you try to use Microsoft Excel and save page in csv format, you'll get semicolon as a delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array::reduce()` to collect values by a key and the convert to CSV:

```js
const data = [
  {
    "Month": "V",
    "6/2022": "2",
    "7/2022": "4",
  },
  {
    "Month": "L",
    "6/2022": "6",
    "7/2022": "8",
  },
];

const obj = data.reduce((obj, item) => {
    for (const key in item) {
        (obj[key] ??= []).push(item[key]);
    }
    return obj;
}, {});

const csv = Object.entries(obj).map(([key, items]) => key + ';' + items.join(';')).join('\n');

console.log(csv);
```

And benchmarking:

[image]

```html
<script benchmark data-count="1">

    const data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Array.from({ length: 1000000 }).reduce(arr => arr.push(...[
        {
            "Month": "V",
            "6/2022": "2",
            "7/2022": "4",
        },
        {
            "Month": "L",
            "6/2022": "6",
            "7/2022": "8",
        },
    ]) && arr, [])));

    // @benchmark Lin Du's 

    Object.keys(data[0])
        .map(k => [k, ...data.map(v => v[k])].join(';'))
        .join('\n');    

    // @benchmark Alexander's

    const obj = data.reduce((obj, item) => {
        for (const key in item) {
            (obj[key] ??= []).push(item[key]);
        }
        return obj;
    }, {});

    Object.entries(obj).map(([key, items]) => key + ';' + items.join(';')).join('\n');

</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = [
  {
    "Month": "V",
    "6/2022": "2",
    "7/2022": "4",
  },
  {
    "Month": "L",
    "6/2022": "6",
    "7/2022": "8",
  },
];

const csv = Object.keys(data[0])
  .map(k => [k, ...data.map(v => v[k])].join(';'))
  .join('\n');

console.log(csv);
```

Comment: benchmarking 2 array items doesn't make much sense. also going `for..in` blows up any functional approach. check this in my answer.